# Swift - How can I decode json string response into a String?

Tags: json, swift, string, decode

Why doesn't this work?

```
let jsonResponse = " \"This is a response\" "

let str = try! JSONDecoder().decode(String.self, from: jsonResponse)

print(str)
```

error: cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Data'

In other languages, like javascript or java/kotlin, converting this response into a string is pretty easy.

JS

```
const s = JSON.parse(" \"This is a response\" ")
```

Kotlin

```
val s = Gson().fromJson(String::class.java, " \"This is a response\" ")
```

But in swift, it doesn't seem this straight forward. Is this response valid json? I assumed that the double quotes would make it a valid json object.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can check if your json is valid [here](https://jsonlint.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the `String` to `Data` first to decode it using `JSONDecoder`:

```
let jsonResponse = " \"This is a response\" "
let data         = Data(jsonResponse.utf8)
let str          = try! JSONDecoder().decode(String.self, from: data)
print(str)
```

Comment: This code doesn't seem to work [here](http://online.swiftplayground.run/), any ideas?

Comment: This code runs perfectly on Xcode-playgrounds download it from [here](https://developer.apple.com/swift-playgrounds/) or if you have Xcode that's more than enough. The thrid-party playground you're using seems to be broken or outdated.